# Xamarin iOS - "Native linking failed for .." with Static Library Bind

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to build an, only iOS, app but I get two errors:

> linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>
> Native linking failed for '/Users/{name}/Desktop/{application name}/{application name}/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone8.1-11.1.2/mtouch-cache/arm64/libSomething.dll.dylib'. Please file a bug report at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com

I get these errors with a dll generated from a binding of a (native obj-c) static library with XCode 9.2

I'm using Visual Studio 7.2 with Xamarin.iOS 11.6.1.2

Comment: It seems like your project can't find the dll .Check if the dll exists or not there.

Comment: thank u @ColeXia but the error was somewhere else, I write the solution below.
Thanks all the same!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it.
The error was in the Static Library, was missing two classes.
I've added these two in XCode and then works.